# Set and clear interval in node js

Tags: node.js

I am learning node js and need some clarification.

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var getResource = function(c) {
  var emitter = new EventEmitter();
  process.nextTick(function() {
    var count = 0;
    emitter.emit("start")
    var t = setInterval(function() {
      c
      emitter.emit("data", ++count);

      if (count === c) {
        emitter.emit("end");
        //clearInterval(t);
      }
    }, 1000)
  });
  return emitter;
}
var r = getResource(5);

r.on("start", function() {
  console.log("I have started");
})

r.on("data", function(d) {
  console.log("Received " + d);
})

r.on("end", function() {
  console.log("I have ended");
})
```

If I uncomment the setInterval part it behaves as expected ie., prints the data until 5 and end event is emitted.

If I comment it, then data is printed until 5 and end event is emitted. After that it runs in indefinite loop and prints continuously. Why is my code 
       if(count === c){...} 
does not check and ends the loop ?

Comment: If your expected behaviour is printing just once after the timer, you should be using `setTimeuot()`

Comment: Hi @AkashDathan,  I don't have any specific requirement, Just learning node js. I don't understand this set and clear interval behaviour

Comment: `setInterval` means schedules repeated execution of callback every delay milliseconds. `clearInterval` means cancels a `Timeout object` created by `setInterval()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `emit` method is a generic one. It just emits an event & optionally passes data.

```
emitter.emit(eventName, data);
```

where `eventName` is a string & `data` is an arbitrary value.

It is up to the programmer to make use of that as per the requirement. 
Passing `end` as event name means nothing to `emit` method, as for the method, it is just another call. In your case, `clearInterval` is needed to actually end `data` events. Only to the receiver of the events, `end` event makes sense.

So, if you emit `end` event, the receiver will know there would be no more `data` event.

Consider emitting `end` event as a signal to receiver. But, you have to actually make sure there are no more events(`data`) after `end` event.

Answer (score 0):

> until `clearInterval` is called, `setInterval` will execute the code
>   in recurring time intervals.

Please refer the NodeJs doc on [Timers](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html).